# I tried to access url params and show page view based url params while paginate using laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I tried to access url params and show page view based url params while paginate from one page to another pagination page as url redirect pagination using laravel paginate. Here i couldn't able to call method while redirect to that next pagination page.

```
Route:
Route::get('/cogs/ddd/{id}/{name}', 'CogsController@showPagenateDetails');

cogsController:
public function showPagenateDetails(Request $request)
    {
        echo "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu";
        return View::make('cogs');
    }

Access paginate url:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/cogs/ddd?id=12&name=uday
```

Comment: do you know the difference between, route parameter & URL query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

As @Webinion commented on your question, it seems you're mixing up route parameters and URL query parameters.

**Route parameters** are segments of a URL, they're part of the path. On the other hand, **URL query parameters**, also known as *query string*, comes after the path, preceded by a question mark (`?`).

In your sample URL, you have query parameters:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/cogs/ddd?id=12&name=uday
```

However, the route you declared expects route parameters. A URL like this would be valid:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/cogs/ddd/12/uday
```

In this case, `12` is the **id**, and `uday` is the **name**.

Also, when using route params, you may add those to your controller method arguments:

```
public function showPagenateDetails(Request $request, $id, $name)
{
// ....
```

Finally, if what you want is using URL query params, change your route path this way:

```
Route::get('/cogs/ddd', 'CogsController@showPagenateDetails');
```

And capture the params through the `get` method from the request:

```
$id = $request->get('id');
$name = $request->get('name');
```

If you want to learn more about Laravel routes and route params, refer to the [Routing chapter of Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing).

Comment: Thanks for your update. Actually our pagination component generate url like using (?) mark. http://127.0.0.1:8080/cogs/ddd?id=12&name=uday
So is there anyway to call ddd method while page load by using this url and get that params?

Comment: I try to access using "ddd" like
Route::get('ddd', 'CogsController@showPagenateDetails');
and get param using $request->all() from showPagenateDetails method. it's working fine. But why "cogs/ddd" not working. Whats wrong with my code could you give suggesstion